# TerminateProcess and deadlocks

Tags: c++, multithreading, process, deadlock

Is it real that the TerminateProcess function in Windows could hang because the threads inside the process were stuck in a deadlock?

Example: Process A is running under Process B's control, now Process A gets into a deadlock and Process B detects this and decides to 'Kill' process A using TerminateProcess.

Would it be successful in killing the hung Process A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all kernel objects held by the process will be released, including locks.

The main problem with TerminateProcess is that the process has no say in the matter: if it's holding on to any global state (files, shared memory, etc) then you have no guarantee those things are in a consistent state after the process is terminated.

Comment: So what could cause it to hang at the time of Killing it and it's mother process to hang as well?

Comment: If it has pending I/O, the kernel waits for pending I/O to complete before terminating the process. If the process is in kernel-mode then it will also wait until that has finished (both of those are quite rare and will usually indicate a bad driver or bad hardware)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. So long as you have the right permissions, `TerminateProcess` will kill the other process dead, regardless of how well hung it is.

Answer (score 0):

`TerminateProcess` will kill each thread (as if `TerminateThread` had been used on each and every thread in the process).

But it won't kill threads that are stuck in the kernel (e.g. due to device driver bug).