# Will WriteFile() be atomic if the process is terminated but the system continues running?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, io, atomic

If my process is terminated at a random moment but the operating system continues to run properly, will Windows guarantee that individual calls to [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx) are atomic (a.k.a. all-or-nothing)?
Or can I get partial/torn writes?

---

#### Note: I am specifically NOT asking for advice on how to practice defensive coding.

This is **strictly** a question about the behavior of the Microsoft Windows ***operating system* itself**.

To be 100% perfectly *crystal clear*, **we can and explicitly *do* trust the user code to behave sanely**. There is ***no undefined behavior*** or anything of the sort. All process terminations are assumed to occur through a **well-defined behavior** such as unhandled exceptions or calls to `TerminateProcess`, **not** memory corruption, etc.

Also, specifically note that there are no C++ destructors to worry about here; this is C.

I hope that puts all the secondary concerns about the user code to rest.

Comment: In general WriteFile isn't atomic regardless, it's only atomic for single sector writes.

Comment: @RossRidge: [citation needed]

Comment: No, a citation isn't what you need.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RossRidge: Well, the reason I said [citation needed] is that not every kernel-mode I/O operation is cancellable. MSDN says ["Most types of operations can be canceled immediately; other operations can continue toward completion before they are actually canceled and the caller is notified."](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/aa363792.aspx) Furthermore, it says nothing about *automatic* cancellations caused by process termination. I don't know if a write operation is auto-cancellable, so if you believe it is, I'd like to see where you got that information from.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: No I haven't tried. But I'm not so certain that's so clear, because the atomicity of a sector write is a guarantee provided by the *storage disk* (e.g. against a power failure, which is a hardware concern), not by the *operating system* (e.g. through transactions, which is a software concern). So I can't tell whether that sentence is referring to hardware interruptions or software interruptions; they seem to be mixing up the two.

Comment: It's the reference to NTFS transactions that convince me.  NTFS transactions are all about operating system guarantees.  At any rate, my experience with MS documentation suggests that you're unlikely to find any explicit statement that there isn't such a guarantee as Windows just isn't documented to that level of detail.  (Of course, you might get lucky.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Well that's why I asked! I'm not so convinced yet. I haven't been able to find it either, but sometimes there are other pieces of information besides documentation out there (presentations by MS, blog posts like the Old New Thing, etc.) that I thought someone might know about.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: You may find this comment interesting as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908603/terminateprocess-and-deadlocks#comment2959197_2908615

Comment: Interruptions of the sort you're referring to aren't the only way a multi-sector write might end up not being atomic. The documentation guarantees that a single sector write is all-or-nothing under all circumstances, including other concurrent accesses. If you don't actually need true atomicity, you should more specific about what consistency guarantees you do need.

Comment: @RossRidge: Everything you just wrote in your comment is true but does not answer the question. Also, please see the comment I just posted a few seconds ago.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to answer you question. That's not what comments are for. The question you linked isn't relevant.

Comment: @RossRidge: I didn't link you a question, I linked you a comment underneath an answer to a question. Did you read the comment? It's very relevant.

Comment: Experimentally, a simple crash or external termination doesn't cause a partial write; termination is indeed postponed until the logical write is completed.  So there might be a guarantee to this effect, though if there were I'd have expected it to be in the docs for WriteFile.  Freeing the buffer *does* cause a partial write, although it doesn't change the length of the file, i.e., nothing happens if the write started at or after the end of the file.

Comment: However, in most cases if the program has crashed you can't guarantee what code may have executed between the point at which things went wrong and the point that user-mode execution stops, so it might free the buffer, either by random chance or because (for example) the runtime is attempting to exit and is running destructors.  YMMV.

Comment: Just in case it is any use to you, I think it should be reasonably safe to assume that if the file length changes then the entire write has been successfully completed, provided you write-protect the buffer ahead of time to ensure that the crash can't mangle the data.  I understand you want a MS guarantee rather than a random opinion, but FWIW. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I think you're overcomplicating it... I'm assuming there is no malicious attacker here. The only possibilities are either that the program runs as intended, or that the program is abruptly terminated either because of something like an unhandled exception or a call to `TerminateProcess`, etc... either way, memory is assumed to be uncorrupted. It's simply a question of whether the OS can terminate a write in the middle.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yeah, that's my understanding too -- I'm under the impression that a write operation currently in kernel mode must always proceed to completion (notwithstanding lower-level errors), but I'd like to double check.

Comment: You don't always need a malicious attacker for code to run out of control and do unexpected things.  But yes, if you have a reasonable idea of the range of possible failure modes, it may be safe to assume a clean (though unplanned) termination.

Comment: @Mehrdad: "*notwithstanding lower-level errors*" which would not be detected nor necessarily reported as the owning/monitoring process is about to die. I'd say, although this is an interessting (academic) discussion, do not rely on anything that happens after UB might have been invoked, at least not in production code.

Comment: @alk: Yes I'm completely aware. Like I said, I'm assuming there is no UB in the code; the behavior of the code is assumed to be completely sane.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes I know, I know... my question is about the operating system behavior, not about how I should practice defensive coding!

Comment: If there's no UB then there's no insane code then there's no crash.

Comment: @Flexo: No, you're wrong. Unhandled exceptions can crash the running process without ever incurring UB.

Comment: I'd say the main issue is that there is no information/documentation on what happens to the buffer used by any pending write-operation, in case the process is (about to) end(ing). So even if the pending I/O would finish succesfully, this is wourth nothing if the data in the buffer written out had been corrupted, as the holding process already freed it.

Comment: @alk: No information where? No information in MSDN, or no information in my question? I hope you mean the former because I've clearly stated several times now that for this question we're **assuming** the user code behaves sanely and won't try to manipulate the buffers and corrupt the data, so the only question remaining is the system behavior, not the user code behavior.

Comment: You might want to make that clearer then with a complete example and consolidate the other comments into the question too.

Comment: I was referring to the system. I'll double check msdn and come back on this later...

Comment: @Flexo: Is that clear now?

Comment: @Downvoters: If you could comment maybe I could actually improve the question...

Comment: @alk: I believe that it's well understood that Windows does not free the individual memory allocations when terminating a process, so the buffers shouldn't go away until the I/O is complete, but I have to admit I don't know exactly where to look to prove it.  Lack of error handling probably isn't a major issue, because (thanks to the Windows cache) disk errors aren't usually reported back to the application *anyway*.  The user gets notified if possible.  I think the main question is whether Windows is entitled to cancel running I/O requests when terminating a process.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. There's nothing in the documentation of WriteFile that says it can be interrupted by a process exit of any kind.

Comment: @EJP: I'm too tired and baffled by your comment so I'll let someone else respond to you.

Comment: @EJP: there's nothing in the documentation for WriteFile that says it *can't* be interrupted by process termination.  Do you have any specific reason to think it can't?  The documentation for TerminateProcess explicitly says that it "requests cancellation of all pending I/O".

Answer (score 3):

`WriteFile` is certainly **not** atomic in the case of your process being terminated while it is executing, it is not even atomic if your process is not being killed.

Also, *"all or nothing written"* is not even a proper definition of an atomic write. All could be written, but intermingled with an independent write from another process. If writes are guaranteed to be atomic, there must be a guarantee (read as: lock) that this doesn't happen.

Apart from the fact that implementing proper atomicity would be considerable extra trouble with very little to gain for the average everyday user,  you can also guess that `WriteFile` is not atomic from:

1. The absence of mention in the API documentation. You can bet that this would be *prominently* mentioned, as it is a really big, distinguishing feature.
2. The presence of the `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` parameter. A write might still fail (e.g. disk full) but if the function was guaranteed to be atomic, you would know that it either succeeded or failed, and you already know how many bytes you were going to write, so returning that number is unnecessary.
3. The presence of [TxF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968806%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Although TxF does a lot more than just making single writes atomic, it is reasonable to assume that Microsoft wouldn't waste considerable time and money in implementing such a beast when "normal" filesystem operations already more or less work the like anyway.
4. No other mainstream operation system that I know of gives such a guarantee. Linux does give a *sort of* atomicity guarantee on `writev` (but not on `write`) insofar as your writes will not be intermingled with writes from other processes. But that is not at all the same thing as guaranteeing atomicity in presence of process termination.

However, overlapped writes on a handle opened with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` are *technically* atomic in respect of process termination (but not in respect of failure, such as disk full or in any other respect!). Saying so is admittedly a bit of a sophistry on an implementation detail, not an actual guarantee given by the operating system, but from a certain point of view it's certainly correct to say so.
A process that is performing an unbuffered, overlapped I/O operation cannot be terminated. That is because the OS is doing DMA transfers into that process' address space. Which of course means that the process cannot be terminated since the OS would reclaim the physical pages. The OS will therefore refuse to terminate a process while such an I/O operation is running.
You can verify this by firing off a couple of big unbuffered overlapped requests (a few GB) and try killing your process in Task Manager. It will only be killed when the I/O is complete (so, after some seconds). That comes as a big surprise when you see it happen for the first time and don't expect it!

Comment: Great point about the true meaning of atomicity, however when I said atomic I really only meant all-or-nothing. (Poor terminology, I know, but I **did** say let's assume the code itself is not the concern here -- so let's assume only one process is using that file. I wasn't intending to discuss concurrent writes.) So can you say the same thing about all-or-nothingness? Is a file opened *with* buffering still not all-or-nothing?

Comment: Buffered writes copy the data to be written to the filesystem cache (as "dirty" pages), and actual writes happen lazily. It is very possible to copy part of the data before your process dies, and the other half thus won't be in the buffers and won't be written. Also there is the issue of metadata. Is metadata updated or not - nobody can tell for sure, but it probably isn't (which would mean writes are _logically_ not visible although they happened physically). The documentation makes no mention and no promises, so you have no way of knowing. The only safe assumption is thus "not atomic".

Comment: Isn't the copying to the filesystem buffer done in kernel-mode though? Process termination requires user-mode system code to be run, so kernel mode has to somehow call user-mode system code, and that can't happen unless the kernel-mode code exits into user-mode cleanly somehow. It seems unlikely that there would be a clean exit-to-user-mode code path in the *middle* of the copy to the filesystem cache (isn't that just a simple memcpy of some sort?), so that's why my conclusion is that it must necessarily be all-or-nothing -- I can't imagine a partial copy to the cache.

Comment: How does termination require user-mode code? It is perfectly possible to use up one's typical two time quantums and be scheduled out. Then someone calls `TerminateProcess`, and your process never runs again. Someone else calling `TerminateProcess` is the only reasonable "random termination" reason anyway, since `WriteFile` won't just crash (no, a segfault won't do, this fails with error code `ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER` but _doesn't_ terminate the process).

Comment: I actually thought some user-mode cleanup would be inevitable (for some reason I thought e.g. APCs must get called when a thread exits), but you're right, that doesn't seem to be the case. However, even forgetting about user mode, my reasoning about the copying procedure stands, doesn't it? i.e. the kernel isn't going to suddenly terminate the kernel thread in the middle of a memcpy to the filesystem buffer, just because a time slice scheduled it out, is it? That would mess up kernel locks -- it would need to transition cleanly out of that copying procedure.

Comment: _Some_ kernel code is inevitably uninterruptible, but surely not all. A single `WriteFile` could potentially take seconds or minutes. Think of copying something like a CD/DVD ISO file on a low end machine which doesn't have an extra gigabyte of buffer available, and the target drive is a SMB share, or a typical cheap USB stick with 5-7 MB/s write speed. And now imagine that's a single-core machine, and you cannot preempt or interrupt the write after it has entered kernel mode. That would lock up the computer so you wouldn't even be able to abort the copy other than by pulling the power plug.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying. I wasn't saying that `WriteFile` is entirely uninterruptible. I was saying that I expect that the portion of its implementation that *copies the user-mode data to the kernel-mode file system cache* would be uninterruptible, since that's *always* going to be fast (it's just a simple memcpy). Once that stage is passed, the filesystem would be free to delay writing the data to the storage medium, and that part is free to take longer if it needs to. But since the data is in its buffer already then you can't see a partial write anymore, right?

Comment: Once the complete data is in the buffers, you can't see a partial write any more, that's right (But mind metadata, such as valid file length!). But getting the data there is a bit more than just a simple `memcpy`, it also involves allocating pages. You are perfectly allowed to write more than fits into the buffer cache at the present time. So it must either work page-by-page and optionally block during commit, or fault during the `memcpy` while the OS swaps out pages or drops them to provide a page to you, or waits for them to become free due to writeback, or whatever.

Comment: If the OS was going to write the data to the FS buffer page-by-page, then a `WriteFile` with a huge buffer wouldn't cause an error. But currently, if you try to pass it a buffer that's humongous (say, a gigabyte) it will fail with some error (I forget what the error was). To me that seems to say the OS is allocating all the pages at once, so I'm not sure whether a partial write would be possible there.